# angularJs - Getting output like this {{student.fullname();}} in my code

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I am trying to run a simple code but its not working. I am getting something like this `{{student.fullname();}}`.

Can help me out ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
FirstName : <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model=student.firstname/> <br> <br>
LastName :<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model=student.lastname/><br> <br>
Your fullName is : {{student.fullname()}}</div>
<script>
var mainApp= angular.module("mainApp",[])
mainApp.controller('studentController',function($scope){
$scope.student={
  firstname="Hariharan",
  lastname="Sriram",
  fullname=function(){
        var obj;
        obj=$scope.student;
        return student.firstname" + "student.lastname;
  };
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "not working" is useless information. Tell us what it does, and what you want it to do instead. Also add any errors you see in your browser's javascript console.

Comment: Object literals (your `$scope.student`) use `:` instead of `=` to assign values to property names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to be wrong in syntax. You are not defining a Javascript:

```
$scope.student = {
    firstname: "Hariharan",
    lastname: "Sriram",
    fullname: function() {
        var obj;
        obj = $scope.student;
        return obj.firstname + "  " + obj.lastname;
    }
};
```

You can also do this directly in your HTML view (another solution):

```
Your fullName is : {{student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName}}</div>
```

In this way, you don't have to write a piece of Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

In your code few syntax errors are there, can you try this:

**Html code**

```
<div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
  FirstName :
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>LastName :
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.lastname" />
  <br>
  <br>Your fullName is : <span ng-bind="student.fullname()"></span>
</div>
```

**Controller code:**

```
$scope.student = {
  firstname: "Hariharan",
  lastname: "Sriram",
  fullname: function() {
    var obj;
    obj = $scope.student;
    return obj.firstname + "  " + obj.lastname;
  }
};
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6jXeB5wamtiOQw7PBev?p=preview)

Comment: Nice. I was trying to work on it, but I'm new to angular. Here are your suggestions in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/qWBsjXiP55IpZfoGsMrp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your provided informations are not enough to help you. as new in angularjs you should learn how to use the console for ease debuging. for your question i think that you forgot to add a semi-colone at the end of the firstline.

```
var mainApp= angular.module("mainApp",[]);
```

and for good practic's you should ident you code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    FirstName :
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.firstname" />
    <br>
    <br>LastName :
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.lastname" />
    <br>
    <br>Your fullName is : <span ng-bind="student.fullname()"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
    mainApp.controller("studentController", ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.student = {
       firstname: "Hariharan",
       lastname: "Sriram",
       fullname: function() {
         var obj;
         obj = $scope.student;
         return obj.firstname + "  " + obj.lastname;
       }
     }
   }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple issues in your code:

1. Within HTML whenever using ng-model you need to add the model within ""
2. You don't need a semicolon in HTML when calling a scope method
3. Within your controller code you needed to specify object in pattern `{key: value}` and not `{key= value}` in javascript.
4. Within your `fullname()` function, if you were referencing `student` in `obj` but still using student object

Below is the updated running snippet for your code

```js
// Code goes here

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.student = {
    firstname: "Hariharan",
    lastname: "Sriram",
    fullname: function() {
      var obj;
      obj = $scope.student;
      return obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
  FirstName :
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>LastName :
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="student.lastname" />
  <br>
  <br>Your fullName is : <span ng-bind="student.fullname()"></span>
</div>
```